# Universal Table/Join Table A Good Idea?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say you have a list of entities: Post, Question, and Gallery and these entities can be liked and commented on by a user and also hold tags.

Would would it be a good idea to compact things so there's not a bunch of tables (**Option 1**) or is it better to create as many tables as necessary although the tables will look very similar to each other (**Option 2**).

**Option 1**

- Create a universal **like_**, **comment**, and **tag** TABLE which holds the 'entity_type' so you know which entity the like belongs to and an **entity** TABLE to ensure data integrity. A good thing about this option is I could add more entities and only have to create 1 table per entity vs 4 (one for the entity, a like join table, a comment join table, a tag join table):

**enitity**

- entity_id PRIMARY KEY

**entity_type**

- en_type TEXT PRIMARY KEY
- description

**post**

- post_id  PRIMARY KEY
- post_id REFERENCES entity(entity_id);

**gallery**

- gallery_id PRIMARY KEY
- gallery_id REFERENCES entity(entity_id)

**question**

- question_id PRIMARY KEY
- question_id REFERENCES entity(entity_id)

**tag**

- tag_id
- tag_name

**like_**

- entity_type
- entity_id
- user_id
- entity_type REFERENCES entity_type(en_type)
- entity_id REFERENCES entity(entity_id);

**comment**

- entity_type
- entity_id
- user_id
- comm
- entity_type REFERENCES entity_type(en_type)
- entity_id REFERENCES entity(entity_id);

**tag_to_entity**

- entity_type
- entity_id
- tag_id

**Option 2**

- Separate everything. Here everything is straight forward but there's a lot more tables.

**tag**

- tag_id
- tag_name

**post**

- post_id PRIMARY KEY

**gallery**

- gallery_id PRIMARY KEY

**question**

- question_id PRIMARY KEY

**like_to_post**

- post_id
- user_id
- post_id REFERENCES post(post_id)

**like_to_gallery**

- gallery_id
- user_id
- gallery_id REFERENCES gallery(gallery_id)

**like_to_gallery**

- question_id
- user_id
- question_id REFERENCES question(question_id)

**comment_to_post**

- post_id
- user_id
- comment_text
- post_id REFERENCES post(post_id)

**comment_to_gallery**

- gallery_id
- user_id
- comment_text
- gallery_id REFERENCES gallery(gallery_id)

**comment_to_question**

- question_id
- user_id
- comment_text
- gallery_id REFERENCES question(question_id)

**tag_to_post**

- post_id
- tag_id
- post_id REFERENCES post(post_id)

**tag_to_gallery**

- gallery_id
- tag_id
- gallery_id REFERENCES gallery(gallery_id)

**tag_to_question**

- question_id
- tag_id
- question_id REFERENCES question(question_id)

Answer (score 1):

I would say option 2 is preferable because:

1. It allows the database to enforce foreign key constraints on you join tables
2. Performance will likely be better because the size of your joins will be much smaller